# How to use class code of vb.net in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having trouble with using my vb.net code in asp.net webpage.

```
<%@ Page  Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="Banking_Application.WebForm1" CodeFile="~/WebForm1.aspx.vb" %>
```

class name is WebForm1. I've written code in a separate file and I want to use it in page.

Like

```
<% Dim total As Integer
    Dim val As tests.WebForm1
    val = New tests.WebForm1
    total = val.TotalBranches()
    total.ToString()
%>
```

I'm new to vb.net and asp.net.

All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: please be more specific, what is your separate file? the code behind `WebForm1.aspx.vb` ? or another class file? and what code from the file you want to use?

Comment: @Banana I write code in another file. I just dont know how to put it in asp.net. File name is webform1. Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all i need to clarify a few things for you:

in Asp.net, you can embed code in your aspx page using `<% %>` code block, or write it in a separate file and use it from there.

in your page declaration, you specify the code behind of your page using the `CodeBehind=` attribute, so if you want to place your code in `WebForm1.vb`, your page declaration should include `CodeBehind="WebForm1.vb"` .

- note: `CodeFile="~/WebForm1.aspx.vb"` is not needed.

the structure of the code behind for you aspx page, should look like that:

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
    Public Function test1()
        Return "test"
    End Function
End Class
```

and you can add more functions as needed. in the example above, i have added a function called `test1` for the purpose of this example.

now, after you have created your code behind in the correct structure, you can call its methods from the aspx page as if it was the same page:

```
<% =test1()
%>
```

this will return `"test"` as specified by the function in code behind.

 you do not need to instantiate the class.

Comment: Thankyou dude. There is one thing that I'm confused with, the other tag in @page i.e. inherits. If you have time please explain this tag in one or two line. Thanks once again.

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx) is a complete list of those attribute and their explanation. In short, the inherits attribute just specifies the class in the codeFile /codeBehind from which your aspx page will inherit. see [.Net Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973803.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing what is happening with the mechanics of asp.net.

You either:

- Write code directly in the aspx page (within the html)
- Or, you wrtie code in the code behind page... your `WebForm1.aspx.vb` page. From the code behind page, you can access and manipulate the server controls that is on the aspx (html) side...

Comment: suppose I write code in webform.vb and I want to use it like  
dim object as webform1 = new webform1 ()
I dont know how to do that in asp page

Comment: Why not work from code behind? Much more organized, easier to handle. More familiar. I've always been of the opinion that in page code, are for things like quickly calling a variable, changing some text, etc. Basic stuff. For more detailed coding, use the codebehind?

Comment: Thanks.
Can you please write the syntax for <@page xxxxxxxxxxx> ??
because I think the problems is in page tag.
seperate code file name is webform1.vb
thanks!

Comment: You're not getting the point. Do NOT write any `vb.net` code in the html (aspx) page. Write your `vb.net` code in the `aspx.vb` page.